# date_diff() works through browser, undefined function via cron

Tags: php, function, undefined, datediff

I'm running php 5.6 and have the following, which works via my browser by throws error Call to Undefined Function via cron:

```
 $startdate = new DateTime('2016-08-30');
 $today = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

 if ( (date_diff($startdate, $today)->format('%a')) % 14 == 0  )
```

phpversion() returns 5.6

Comment: And you expect us to help you, with this little information, how?

Comment: The scripts may be running from different config settings. From a working file, and from the cron, run the following 2 lines: `$contents=__FILE__.' has INI: '.php_ini_loaded_file().PHP_EOL;` `file_put_contents('/pah/to/log.txt',$contents ,FILE_APPEND);`. Then open `log.txt` and compare the locations of the INI files. Are they the same?

Comment: @BeetleJuice that or he is running a flavor of Linux that supports SCL. Check to make sure your PATH is set correctly in your crontab

Comment: @BeetleJuice ding ding ding! I thought it might be a php.ini issue. One is /usr/php/56/etc/php.ini , the other /etc/php.ini . Unfortunately, neither of these files are showing up in my ssh session (I'm a newb if you hadn't figured)